# how to get int value for pointer

Tags: c++

I have a socket wraper and it has the `RecvData` that returns an `int`:

```
int RecvData(void* buff, int bufferSize){
    return recv(hSocket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff), bufferSize, 0);
}
```

also I have this WebServer function `ReceiveLine` to get an HTTP request:

```
static string ReceiveLine()
{
    Socket* sock;
    std::string ret;
    while (1) {
        char r;

        switch(sock->SendData(&r,sizeof(r))) {
        case 0: // not connected anymore;
            return "";
        case -1:
            if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                return ret;
            } else {
                // not connected anymore
                return "";
            }
        }

        ret += r;
        if (r == '\n')  return ret;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The problem is that in the `switch` statement I have this error:

```
Socket* sock;  pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
```

Comment: The title does not appear to have anything to do with your problem. The problem is that there is no definition for Socket.

Comment: (It's also strange that your "Receive" function calls SendData.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An incomplete class means you have declared the `Socket` class but not defined it. Maybe it's been forward declared but you never included the `.h` file containing the definition.